# Guzzle 6: no more json() method for responses

Tags: php, guzzle

Previously in Guzzle 5.3:

```
$response = $client->get('http://httpbin.org/get');
$array = $response->json(); // Yoohoo
var_dump($array[0]['origin']);
```

I could easily get a PHP array from a JSON response. Now In Guzzle 6, I don't know how to do. There seems to be no `json()` method anymore. I (quickly) read the doc from the latest version and don't found anything about JSON responses. I think I missed something, maybe there is a new concept that I don't understand (or maybe I did not read correctly).

Is this (below) new way the only way?

```
$response = $client->get('http://httpbin.org/get');
$array = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true); // :'(
var_dump($array[0]['origin']);
```

Or is there an helper or something like that?

Answer (score 361, accepted):

I use `json_decode($response->getBody())` now instead of `$response->json()`.

I suspect this might be a casualty of PSR-7 compliance.

Comment: Nothing in the documentation that makes this explicit but it does appear they've phased out the `$response->json()` helper.

Comment: If you're expecting an array response like how the original `->json()` worked, use `json_decode($response->getBody(), true)` instead to get an array instead of a stdObject

Comment: Using `strict_types`, I needed to cast the Guzzle response body to string  before decoding it: `json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true)`

Comment: I always liked to use `\GuzzleHttp\json_decode` (or `\GuzzleHttp\Utils::jsonDecode` depending on the Guzzle version you're on) which has a compatible signature to `\json_decode`, but throws an exception if there's an error, leveraging proper err handling.

Comment: Under `strict_types`, you can cast to a `string` as @YoanTournade suggested or instead use `$response->getBody()->getContents()`, which returns a string.

Comment: @AdrianFöder You can do this quite easily with `json_decode($json, $assoc, $depth, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR)`, but you'll have to wrap the function yourself if you still want that convenience.

Answer (score 131):

You switch to:

```
json_decode($response->getBody(), true)
```

Instead of the other comment if you want it to work exactly as before in order to get arrays instead of objects.

Answer (score 38):

I use `$response->getBody()->getContents()` to get JSON from response.
Guzzle version 6.3.0.

Comment: Calling `getContents()` in the response body will empty the stream and the next call to `getContents()` will return empty. If you want to get the body as string use: `strval($response->getBody())`

Comment: I wish this comment was higher. I was logging my response using getContent and when I went to parse a line later, my array was empty. Cost me hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

If you guys still interested, here is my workaround based on Guzzle [middleware](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/handlers-and-middleware.html) feature:

1. Create `JsonAwaraResponse` that will decode JSON response by `Content-Type` HTTP header, if not - it will act as standard Guzzle Response:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace GuzzleHttp\Psr7;


   class JsonAwareResponse extends Response
   {
       /**
        * Cache for performance
        * @var array
        */
       private $json;

       public function getBody()
       {
           if ($this->json) {
               return $this->json;
           }
           // get parent Body stream
           $body = parent::getBody();

           // if JSON HTTP header detected - then decode
           if (false !== strpos($this->getHeaderLine('Content-Type'), 'application/json')) {
               return $this->json = \json_decode($body, true);
           }
           return $body;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create [Middleware](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/handlers-and-middleware.html) which going to replace Guzzle PSR-7 responses with above Response implementation:

   ```
   <?php

   $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

   /** @var HandlerStack $handler */
   $handler = $client->getConfig('handler');
   $handler->push(\GuzzleHttp\Middleware::mapResponse(function (\Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response) {
       return new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\JsonAwareResponse(
           $response->getStatusCode(),
           $response->getHeaders(),
           $response->getBody(),
           $response->getProtocolVersion(),
           $response->getReasonPhrase()
       );
   }), 'json_decode_middleware');
   ```

After this to retrieve JSON as PHP native array use Guzzle as always:

```
$jsonArray = $client->get('http://httpbin.org/headers')->getBody();
```

*Tested with guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.3.3*

Comment: This is some good stuff. Using in a Rest API Client task that i just picked up at work. I do have one question about your answer though. Was your JsonAwareResponse class intended to be under the GuzzleHttp namespace? I ended up just creating that class under my own namespace, but for a second I was searching around GuzzleHttp's codebase looking for that class. :) Thanks again!

Comment: Don't use this solution because it breaks PSR-7 interface `MessageInterface`. With PSR-7 there is no legal solution to patch this interface to return decoded JSON from `getBody()` method.

Comment: A potential solution to the problem @SergeyNevmerzhitsky mentions, could be to turn JsonAwareResponse into a decorator instead, and then implement `__call()` to forward calls to the actual response. Then you can just add in a `getJson()` or whatever you want.

Comment: @SergeyNevmerzhitsky Then PSR-7 is a bad standard and should be deprecated and replaced (ths is true for almost all PSR standards, but I digress). To [quote](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/blog/2018/a-case-study-in-not-being-a-jerk-in-open-source) "There are competent people on standards bodies. But they make mistakes, and the translation of intent to English isn't always perfect. In this case, the standard conflicts with reality, so we ignore the standard. "

Answer (score 8):

`$response` is instance of PSR-7 `ResponseInterface`. For more details see https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/#3-interfaces

`getBody()` returns [`StreamInterface`](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/#34-psrhttpmessagestreaminterface):

```php
/**
 * Gets the body of the message.
 *
 * @return StreamInterface Returns the body as a stream.
 */
public function getBody();
```

`StreamInterface` implements `__toString()` which does

> Reads all data from the stream into a string, from the beginning to end.

**Therefore, to read body as string, you have to cast it to string:**

`$stringBody = $response->getBody()->__toString()`

---

### Gotchas

1. `json_decode($response->getBody()` is not the best solution as it magically casts stream into string for you. `json_decode()` requires string as 1st argument.
2. Don't use `$response->getBody()->getContents()` unless you know what you're doing. If you read documentation for `getContents()`, it says: `Returns the remaining contents in a string`. Therefore, calling `getContents()` reads the rest of the stream and calling it again returns nothing because stream is already at the end. You'd have to rewind the stream between those calls.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the `StreamInterface` behavior, I'm going to make explicit the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `->getContents()` doesn't return jSON response, instead it returns as text.

You can simply use `json_decode`

Comment: It returns JSON as text, not HTML.