# How to force Guzzle to return JSON response instead of full message?

Tags: php, request, guzzle

When I am sending a request with Guzzle, it returns a full error message without parsing the JSON inside. Here is how it looks:

> """ Client error: `POST
>   http://someurl.com` resulted in a
>   `409 Conflict` response:\n {\r\n   "errors": [\r\n
>       "Prospect is already in this campaign"\r\n   ]\r\n }\n """

When I am sending the same request via Postman, it does return the response message parsed correctly.

[image]

How can I make Guzzle to return only the message - not the full response?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32857508/4248328

Comment: @AlivetoDie this answer does not help me

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you get the string above. Looks like a Guzzle's exception converted to a string. BTW, the string contains the same data as you see in Postman.

Just use `$response->getBody()->getContents()` as [Alive to Die suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768666/how-to-force-guzzle-to-return-json-response-instead-of-full-message#comment78495500_45768666).

Comment: I did see that response does contain JSON from Postman. The method that you have posted does not help unfortunately :/

Comment: Then the problem is unclear. Please, update your ticket with the code example of other details.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same problem as you. You'd have to setup the Guzzle call this way:

```
$res = $client->request('POST','contactForm',[
    'http_errors'=>false,
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json'
    ]
]);
```

The key here is the 'http_errors' => false row. This would remove the error string and simply return the JSON data.

Hope that answers that.