# Why I can't convert this object (representing a web service response) into String? Some doubts about PHP object

Tags: php, laravel, php-5.3, guzzle

I am absolutly new in **PHP** (I came from Java that is strongly typed) and I am going crazy trying to understand why I can't convert into a string this object and some object concept in PHP.

So I have this code doLogin() method (into a **Laravel** controller class):

```
public function doLogin(){

    $userName = Input::get('username');
    $pswd = Input::get('password');

    //------------------------------------------
    // Guzzle clint used to perform REST call:
    //------------------------------------------
    $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Do the REST call and obain the response:
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $response = $client->get('http://localhost:8080/Accomodation/7');

    // Decode the response into an object:
    $dettaglioHotel = json_decode($response->getBody());

    //Console::info('username: ' + $userName);
    //Console::info('password ' + $pswd);

    \Log::info('username: '.$userName);
    \Log::info('password '.$pswd);
    //\Log::info('hotel: '.$dettaglioHotel);
    \Log::info('response status code: '.(string)$response->getStatusCode());
    \Log::info('response: '.(string)$dettaglioHotel);

    return view('dashboard-hotel');
}
```

So as you can see in the previus method I am using **Guzzle** library to perform a REST call.

My doubts are:

1) Into **PhpStorm** (the used IDE), passing the mouse on the **get()** method it say to me that the returned object have type **ResponseInterface** that is an **interface** and not a concrete class type.

So what exactly means? That doing:

```
$response = $client->get('http://localhost/Accomodation/7');
```

it return a generic object that implements the **ResponseInterface** interface? Php is automatically building something like a generic object implementing this interface or what?

2) Passing the mouse on the **json_decode()** function, this line:

```
$dettaglioHotel = json_decode($response->getBody());
```

the IDE say a message as **"Multiple implementation"** and show that there are these 2 implementations:

**FIRST IMPLEMENTATION:** json_decode .../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php json_decode

**SECOND IMPLEMENTATION:** C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/PhpStorm 2016.3.2/plugins/php/lib/php.jar!/stubs/standard/json.php

It have to use the first one (related to **Guzzle**) but I am not sure that is using the right one.

3) Finnally I am trying to convert into a **String** and print in the log this object containing the response decodification, in this way:

```
$dettaglioHotel = json_decode($response->getBody());
```

and then:

```
\Log::info('response: '.(string)$dettaglioHotel);
```

But doing in this way when try to convert into strung (by **(string)$dettaglioHotel**) the application crash and I obtain this error message:

```
in LoginBetriviusController.php line 56
at HandleExceptions->handleError('4096', 'Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string', 'C:\Users\Andrea\Documents\Betrivius\WorkSpace\betriviusExtranet\app\Http\Controllers\LoginBetriviusController.php', '56', array('userName' => 'aaa', 'pswd' => 'ddd', 'client' => object(Client), 'response' => object(Response), 'dettaglioHotel' => object(stdClass))) in LoginBetriviusController.php line 56
at LoginBetriviusController->doLogin()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(LoginBetriviusController), 'doLogin'), array()) in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('doLogin', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(LoginBetriviusController), 'doLogin') in Route.php line 190
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 144
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 653
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 655
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 629
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('C:\Users\Andrea\Documents\Betrivius\WorkSpace\betriviusExtranet\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

What it exactly means? Why I can't convert it into a string? How can I see the content of this object?

Comment: I think the last bit makes sense since `json_decode` would return an `stdObject` which doesn't implement `__toString` https://3v4l.org/cX18r. I suppose you could log  `$response->getBody()` which is already a string?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. … passing the mouse on the `get()` method it say to me that the returned object have type `ResponseInterface` that is an interface and not a concrete class type

Well, the method *will* return some concrete object of a specific type. PHP won't do any magic with some ad-hoc object as you suggest. It simply means that the object returned by `get()` will adhere to (`implement`) the `ResponseInterface`. You can treat the returned object as possessing all methods and properties described in that interface. *What class instance exactly will be used is irrelevant.* You use interfaces instead of concrete classes wherever possible to keep flexibility in your implementation to swap out concrete classes when necessary, yet still being compatible with a defined interface.

> 2. the IDE say a message as "Multiple implementation" and show that there are these 2 implementations

That means the same function is implemented twice in different files. Which version will be used will be decided at runtime based on various factors. Most likely Guzzle carries a fallback implementation of `json_decode` *in case the PHP installation doesn't have it installed.* At runtime Guzzle would conditionally define `json_decode` as a polyfill if necessary. This does not typically have to concern you; you can assume the core PHP implementation will be used. Either way, both implementations should act identically, otherwise you'll have a bit of a compatibility problem.

(It appears as if Guzzle defines [`GuzzleHttp\json_encode`](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/functions.php#L300) in its own namespace, so it's a bit weird that the IDE picks it up as identical to the non-namespaced implementation; maybe a problem of the IDE…)

> 3. Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Well, you cannot convert an object to a string. It's undefined what the result is supposed to be. What *does* the string representation of an object look like…? Perhaps you want to `json_encode` it, which is *a* string representation of an object. Or `var_export` perhaps. Or `var_dump`, or any other specific function which defines a behaviour for how it will turn objects into strings.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be to change this line:

```
// Decode the response into an object:
$dettaglioHotel = json_decode($response->getBody());
```

to

```
// Decode the response into an object:
$dettaglioHotel = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

The reason being that `getBody()` returns an [`EntityBody`](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/response.html#response-body) object, and when you `json_decode` that object... well, I'm not really sure what happens. But I doubt it's what you would expect.

Note that using `json_decode` without the second parameter set to `true` will also give you an object. Generally if I'm going to log these I will just use `Log::info(json_encode($theObject));`.

EDIT: It looks like Guzzle actually does implement a version of `json_decode`, so your code will actually work in that case. Logging with `json_encode()` will fix your problem though.

Comment: Well, really, `$response` appears to have a `->json()` method built-in…

Comment: @deceze it looks like, depending on the Guzzle version, [`->json()` may not be implemented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30530172/guzzle-6-no-more-json-method-for-responses)

Comment: OK. You should probably link to a more up-to-date documentation then; I just stumbled across it in *your* link.